# R Language: How to print the first or last rows of a data set?

Tags: r

I can print first n rows by the following command:

```
> dataset[1:n, ]
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Also, how can I print the last rows of a data set?

Comment: Mrflick's answer is probably the easiest way. In addition if you want to subset with `[` you can use: `n <- nrow(dataset); dataset[(n-10):n, ]` to subset the last 10 rows of the data.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you want to print the last 10 lines, use

```
tail(dataset, 10)
```

for the first 10, you could also do

```
head(dataset, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will modify my question to include both first and last rows so that the answer is useful to others. :)